# Network Traffic caused by Word 2016 during first run on Profile

Tags: networking, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, bandwidth, network-traffic

Work on a campus with over 600 student computers.
Completing Windows 10 upgrades with Office 2016.
When students launch Word 2016 for the first time the machine starts downloading "something" from *.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com. Normally around 35MB-40MB.

Not typically a problem unless 20-30 users launch Word at the same time. Brings our network to a craw for about 2 minutes.

Whatever Microsoft is downloading it is profile based so if a different student uses that computer it does it again.

One solution I have found is to use a GPO to prevent office products from using the Internet completely. This is not a good solution as it blocks ALL internet based activities in all Office products.

Questions: Has anyone else seen this activity? Has anyone found a way to locally cache the files so it does not need to reach the outside world?

Comment: That's may be the telemetry data collection from Microsoft. You may block those telemetry from local GPO. See this [discussion](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a9e332df-0895-4da9-9733-4d2bcfa4919c/disable-office-telemetry-data-collection?forum=officeitpro). You may find many articles leave to stop telemetry in Google.

Comment: You should specify if you deployed C2R or MSI version of Office, and what method you used to do that. I.e. Online, network share, etc.

Comment: Side note: In my experience, when a typical user says their Internet connection seems slow, it's usually due to high latency, not low bandwidth. Saturating a broadband connection should *not* cause a latency spike; if it does, you have a well-known, fixable problem called "bufferbloat", where a buggy router is buffering too much and not letting TCP's Congestion Control algorithm work. To confirm, run http://speedtest.dslreports.com/ (note: this is NOT Ookla's Speedtest.net) to get your bufferbloat grade. Maybe do it once when the network is normal, and once when the network is "crawling".